# Parsing MongoLab JSON with GSON

Tags: android, gson, okhttp

I am using OkHttp to make a REST call to my MongoLab database and I am able to print out the JSON data just fine. However, I am having trouble mapping that JSON data into a class with GSON on Android.

JSON Data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5649112ae4b02e2b2edaba79"
        },
        "classroom": {
            "student1": {
                "name": "mehdi",
                "age": 21,
                "course": "Web"
            },
            "student2": {
                "name": "mkyong",
                "age": 29,
                "course": "Java"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

My class:

```
static class School {
    Map<String, Student> classroom;
}

static class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String course;
}
```

When I run it I get this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.IOException: closed
```

I have tested other non-MongoLab JSON data and it works, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Classroom should be a JSONArray not JSONObject.

```
[
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5649112ae4b02e2b2edaba79"
            },
            "classroom": [
                {
                    "name": "mehdi",
                    "age": 21,
                    "course": "Web"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mkyong",
                    "age": 29,
                    "course": "Java"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

and then you can do like this to get an Array :

```
List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject data=new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray dataArray=data.getJSONArray("classroom");
for(int n = 0; n < dataArray.length(); n++)
{
   JSONObject object = dataArray.getJSONObject(n);
   result.add(gson.fromJson(object.toString(), Student.class));
}
```

Or easier way

```
JSONObject data=new JSONObject(json);
List<Student> result = gson.fromJson(data.getString("classroom"), new TypeToken<List<Student>>(){}.getType());
```